# python .apply() throwing ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I'm trying to do some string checks, however I'm getting this error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

What does it mean?

Code:

```
#get name titles
def process_name(name):

    if 'Mr' in name:
        return 'Mr'
    elif ('Mrs' in name) or ('Miss' in name):
        return 'Mrs'
    elif 'Master' in name:
        return 'Ms'
    else:
        return 'Other'


df['Name_Title']=df['Name'].apply(process_name)
```

Dataframe:

[image]

Comment: I'm not getting this error. Please post your dataframe (not as an image).

Comment: What is your `pandas` version? Do you create indices for this dataset explicitly?

Comment: `Pandas version: 0.20.3`. I've added and manipulated, dropped few fields from this dataset and the one in images is the final now & i'm running my code on this structure. The `dataframe` is quite large

Comment: this is not a `machine-learning` question - please do not spam the tag (edited & removed)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have duplicated indices. You can find them by using the [`.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) method on the `Index`. Either:

#### 1. Set the new column with the existing index:

```
df['Name_Title'] = df['Name'].apply(process_name).values
```

#### 2. Reset the index and proceed as before:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['Name_Title'] = df['Name'].apply(process_name)
```

**Note:** Unless you have a good reason indices should be distinct in a pandas DataFrame.

Comment: it's solved, I moved my cell up before any other changes were made to `dataframe`

Comment: @JaskaranSinghPuri Great - please post your solution, close your question, or mark an accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to misplacement of my function, it had to be placed before any other modifications were made to the dataframe or its structure or as the 1st modification.